# Wordpress WP_Query offset parameter not working with search parameter

Tags: wp-query, ajax, search, offsets

On a wordpress query every time i add the 's' parameter the 'offset' and 'posts_per_page' will not work, it will query all posts by using the 's' parameter only, why is that? am I missing something?

Basically i'm creating something like ajax load more plugin, the plugin doesn't suit what i need so i'm improvising one using wordpress ajax with search and need to offset some results for load more functionality.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'offset' => '2',
    's' => 'a',
    'category__not_in' => array(41),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$psps = $query->get_posts();
```

Comment: Does it make any difference to add `'suppress_filters' => true`  ?

Comment: @birgire i'm afraid but i can't find the 'suppress_filters' parameter in the wordpress codex for wp_query??

Comment: I don't know about the Codex, but I can just refer you to the [source code of `WP_Query`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php#L3054), because there might be some `posts_where` filters interfering with your query that.